# How get current coordinates from android GoogleMaps?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, location

Method getMyLocation was deprecated. What can we use to retrieve current coordinates? I interested simple way first.

Comment: As stated here https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#public-methods you can use FusedLocationProviderApi instead and you can see the MyLocationDemoActivity in the sample applications folder for example code

Comment: I already have a MyLocationDemoActivity, but not understand how can get current latitude&longitude.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the `GoogleApiClient`, it basically does all that for you, the only other thing you need to do is have a `locationListener` in place which comes with a `onLocationChanged(new location)` method that you can use to get the latest coordinates, from the `locationChanged` firstly its advisable to check if the location has `accuracy` by doing something like `

```
       if (!location.hasAccuracy())
            return;
        if(location.getAccuracy() > 20)
            return;`
```

The higher the accuracy the less accurate basically because accuracy is in meters, so in my case anything with accuracy higher than 20 is not needed because I will be getting coordinates within a 20m, so now you can get the coordinates like

```
        location.getLatitude();
        location.getLongitude();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, getMyLocation() is deprecated.
You can use the [LocationClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html) API instead. If you see the LocationClient class, you will find the **getLastLocation()** method that returns a Location object. With that location object, you can get the coordinates by calling the getLatitude() and getLongitude().

Hope that helps.